# how can I synchronize a call to my webservice and displaying the data on the map (with marker clustering) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, nsoperation, markerclusterer

I'm writing an app that displays lots of points on the map. I can fetch all of them as a json and put it on the map, but then it's just too many points, so I thought about implementing marker cluster. Since I'm working in Swift, I've decided to use this library: https://github.com/ribl/FBAnnotationClusteringSwift

To avoid heavy data usage on my map I've created a backend webservice that gets as a parameters current user location and visible radius. As an answer it returns a JSON with gps coordinates of points of interest.

Since I'm using `AlamoFire` and `SwiftyJSON`, I created a method to fetch records from my webservice and as you can see below, it uses the current center of the map (lat and lon) and also visible radius:

```
func fetchRecords(radius: Double, lat: Double, lon: Double){
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://mywebservice/records", parameters: ["long": lon, "lat": lat, "radius": radius ])
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    self.array.removeAll()
                    if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        for requestJSON in jsonData {
                            if let request = SingleRecord.fromJSON(JSON(requestJSON)){

                                let pinOne = FBAnnotation()
                                pinOne.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: request.latitude, longitude: request.longitude)
                                self.array.append(pinOne)

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    self.clusteringManager.addAnnotations(self.array)

                case .Failure(let error):
                    print("SWITCH ERROR")
                    print(error)
                }

        }
    }
```

I'm fetching records for the current position and I'm creating a single `FBAnnotation()` for each record. Also, I'm appending all points to the array `self.array'. So far so good.

I want to fetch always actual data from the server, so I've decided to implement method `regionDidChangeAnimated`:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

    self.center = mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude.description
    self.radius = self.getRadius(mapView)


    NSOperationQueue().addOperationWithBlock({

        self.fetchRecords(self.radius, lat: self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, lon: self.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude)

        let mapBoundsWidth = Double(self.mapView.bounds.size.width)

        let mapRectWidth:Double = self.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width

        let scale:Double = mapBoundsWidth / mapRectWidth
        let annotationArray = self.clusteringManager.clusteredAnnotationsWithinMapRect(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, withZoomScale:scale)

        self.clusteringManager.displayAnnotations(annotationArray, onMapView:self.mapView)

    })
```

}

What I did above is to - first - fetch all current records for the given position and then use the prepared code from `FBAnnotationClusteringSwift`.

But it doesn't work and I suspect it's because of the threading issue, maybe the `array` is not yet filled, or something (?), but the result is as follows:

when I open the map I see:

[image]

but when I slightly move the map, suddenly the markers increment:

[image]

and with every move happens the same:

[image]

and so on. The same happens when I zoom in the map, even when there's one marker cluster left in the middle of the screen - with every zoom step it increases its number instead of changing to a single pin. I tried to remove all the elements from the array every time after calling `fetchRecords`, but it also didn't help.

Does anyone know what might be the issue here? I know it's a rare topic, but maybe someone could give me any hint with that, I will really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a completion handler in your fetch function

```
func fetchRecords(radius: Double, lat: Double, lon: Double, completionHandler: (() -> Void)?){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://mywebservice/records", parameters: ["long": lon, "lat": lat, "radius": radius ])
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                self.array.removeAll()
                if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for requestJSON in jsonData {
                        if let request = SingleRecord.fromJSON(JSON(requestJSON)){

                            let pinOne = FBAnnotation()
                            pinOne.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: request.latitude, longitude: request.longitude)
                            self.array.append(pinOne)

                        }
                    }
                }
                //TODO: -Clean your data before adding new things

                self.clusteringManager.addAnnotations(self.array)
                //call the closure after everything is done
                completionHandler()

            case .Failure(let error):
                print("SWITCH ERROR")
                print(error)
            }

    }
}
```

And use it in the main function

```
self.fetchRecords(self.radius, lat: self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, lon: self.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude) { [weak self] in

    let mapBoundsWidth = Double(self?.mapView.bounds.size.width)

    let mapRectWidth:Double = self?.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width

    let scale:Double = mapBoundsWidth / mapRectWidth
    let annotationArray = self?.clusteringManager.clusteredAnnotationsWithinMapRect(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, withZoomScale:scale)

    self?.clusteringManager.displayAnnotations(annotationArray, onMapView:self?.mapView)
}
```

This way you will make sure that the `self?.clusteringManager.displayAnnotations` is done after your fetch

Comment: Thanks for that, one more thing though - this line `self.clusteringManager.removeAll()` brings me error that `value of type FBClusteringManager has no member removeAll`... Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: ok :D maybe there is a function to clear `clusteringManager`? FYI i added o comment clear your data before updating :) sorry about the confusion

Comment: Thanks :) I'm looking at the `clusteringManager` class now here https://github.com/ribl/FBAnnotationClusteringSwift/blob/master/Pod/Classes/FBClusteringManager.swift and I don't see any method for clearing the data, so I though maybe it would be possible to write one there, but to be honest - I just don't know how to affect their code, do you have any idea maybe about it while looking at that piece of code? :|

Comment: first question will be have you tried without clearing? or you are sure that you need to do it?

Comment: ok so there is `setAnnotations(annotations:[MKAnnotation])` witch will reinitialise `FBQuadTree`, witch is responsible of the annotations array so you could use  `self.clusteringManager.setAnnotations(self.array)` instead of `self.clusteringManager.addAnnotations(self.array)`, but make sure what you want to do, clear or add :).

Comment: Hey, changing `addAnnotations` to `setAnnotations` worked, thank you very much!! I will accept your answer as `the one` since it helped me a lot(!), just one last question - could you point me on the mechanism in swift that would show e.g. a `please wait` msg or some other indicator during loading data on the map? :)

Comment: This my friend is on your discretion and design, you can use activity indicator.